# Java Spring query with Oracle

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc, nativequery

I'm facing a problem where I got

```
"oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01722: invalid number"
```

while trying to run query in my console, in the other hand I got the exact number that I want when I run it in DBeaver.

Here's my specification:

Oracle Table:

```
String accNumber;
String date;
String credit;
```

Oracle data example:

| accNumber | date | credit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022/12/12 | 2313.12 |
| 1 | 2022/12/12 | 23515 |
| 1 | 2022/12/13 | 13415.25 |

When I run query

```
"SELECT SUM(credit) FROM transfer_history"
```

in DBeaver, it runs well and I receive 39242.37

But when I run the same query in spring boot using

```
@Query(value = "SELECT SUM(credit) FROM table", nativeQuery = true),
```

I receive

```
"oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01722: invalid number".
```

Please help

Comment: your table is really called, "table?"  Show all DDL.

Comment: its actually called transfer_history